# Using Android shared preferences to save an activitys background color

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

On my app I can change my activity background color by using a dialog.

I'm trying to use shared preferences so that the background color remains changed when I restart the app on my phone.

How do can I change my code so that it works?

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {



    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);               

        if (preferences.getString("clicked", "yes").equals("nope")){
            // it never been clicked
        }else{
            // it has been clicked before do whatever you want with the background
        }

    }

    private static void setButtonPref(Context ctx, String clicked)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("clicked", clicked);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public void showThemes (){
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.theme_list, new String[]{"Green", "Pink", "Orange", "Blue"}));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            // arg0 is your adapter, arg1 is the view clicked, arg2 is the position and arg3 is the id.
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch(arg2){
                    case(0):
                        View someView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                        View root = someView.getRootView();
                        root.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                        setButtonPref(context, "yes");

                        /*Window window = this.getWindow();
                        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                        window.setStatusBarColor(0xFF00FF00);*/


                        break;
                    case(1):
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;

                    case(2):
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case(3):
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coming soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Themes");
        dialog.setContentView(listView);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onCreate()` your `SharedPreferences preferences` will be **null**, As you have to initialize it inside of  `onCreate()` so put line,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

inside of `onCreate()` before accessing it, like,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
      if (preferences.getString("clicked", "yes").equals("nope")){
          // it never been clicked
      } else {
          // it has been clicked before do whatever you want with the background
      }
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);    
}
```

One more thing as there any code which will affect your layout then make changes on before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`

Comment: thanks! on this line: setButtonPref(context, "yes"); I have the error "cannot resolve symbol " on context. Can you help me fix that?

Comment: @user1353517 - Replace `context` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. it worked :) can I simply edit the if statement in the on create if I want to add more colors?

Comment: @user1353517 - Yes, You can add other entries in SharedPreferences and with that get values from it and just compare in if statement. Happy Coding..:)

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
editor.commit();
```

to

```
editor.apply();
```